# Image data into URI breaks in Samsung S3 Android web browser

Tags: android, html, webview, samsung-mobile, data-uri-scheme

We are using webview based app. Calling html pages with base64 image (image data into URI). Lunch our app then, we got the images with base64 url (image data into URI). But when we kill the app and re-launch. Then images are not displaying only on Samsung S3.

Whereas on all other devices, it is working fine.

Comment: Please share some code!

Comment: The above base64 string is an invalid data for image. Check if this is the complete encoded string. Check out his [http://jsbin.com/sodikari/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/sodikari/1/edit) I have placed a valid base64 beside your data and it loads fine.

Comment: Hi Rahul check with this one
<img style="border-radius:3px;vertical-align:middle;" width="48" height="28" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">

Comment: Still the same result... [http://jsbin.com/sodikari/2/edit](http://jsbin.com/sodikari/2/edit) considering the size of your string, i guess your image should be very small.

Comment: <img style="border-radius:3px;vertical-align:middle;" width="48" height="28" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQ‌​VQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
working for me http://jsbin.com/kunohalu/1/edit

Comment: Its very strange the code you have pasted in the above comment is exactly the same thing and yet the first one does not work and second example works just fine.

Comment: When we kill the app and re-launch. Then images are not displaying only on Samsung S3 webview.